# Python list iteration exhaustion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

How do i iterate over two lists simultaneously, One list is bigger than the second one. So the second one exhausts. I want to start the smaller list again till the bigger one exhausts

```
_list = [ 19 , 74, 544, 39, 00, 34, 44, 593, 33, 2123, 22]
_list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Things i have tried:

I used itertools.zip_longest but i don't know what to use in fillvalue.

Needed Output:

The output i desire : `(19, 0), (74, 1) ----- (34, 5) (44, 0) (593, 1)` until the bigger list exhausts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*One list is bigger than the second one. So the second one exhausts. I want to start the smaller list again till the bigger one exhausts*

You might combine [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and `zip` following way

```
import itertools
li1 = [19, 74, 544, 39, 00, 34, 44, 593, 33, 2123, 22]
li2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in zip(li1, itertools.cycle(li2)):
    print(i)
```

output

```
(19, 0)
(74, 1)
(544, 2)
(39, 3)
(0, 4)
(34, 0)
(44, 1)
(593, 2)
(33, 3)
(2123, 4)
(22, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Something easier to understood.
Doesn't matter which list is bigger, the code will take care of it.

```
list1 = [ 19 , 74, 544, 39, 00, 34, 44, 593, 33, 2123, 22]
list2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
len1 = len(list1)
len2 = len(list2)
lenMax = max(len1, len2)
for i in range(lenMax):
    print("({},{})".format(list1[i%len1], list2[i%len2]), end=", ")
print()
```

Comment: I like the idea of finding the longer of the two lists to drive your for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Daweo's answer:

```
_list = [ 19 , 74, 544, 39, 00, 34, 44, 593, 33, 2123, 22]
_list1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
_merged = [(v, _list1[i % len(_list1)]) for i, v in enumerate(_list)]
print(_merged)
```

should give you:

```
[(19, 0), (74, 1), (544, 2), (39, 3), (0, 4), (34, 0), (44, 1), (593, 2), (33, 3), (2123, 4), (22, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try itertools.cycle:

```
result_list = []
cycle_list = itertools.cycle(shorter_list)
for i in loner_list():
    result_list.append((i, next(cycle_list))
```